# Determine Characteristic Boundary of PDE

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this exercise:

Determine a characteristic boundary condition for the equation $u_{x_1}+uu_{x_2}=0$

I will start with the definition.
The quasilinear equation has the form
$a(x,y,u)u_x+b(x,y,u)u_y=c(x,y,u)$

$u_{|\Gamma}=\Phi$

The Boundary Condition $(\Gamma=(\gamma_1(r),\gamma_2(r)),\Phi)$ is called non characteristic boundary data if
$(a(\gamma_1(r),\gamma_2(r),\Phi(r)),b(\gamma_1(r),\gamma_2(r),\Phi(r))) \cdot (-\gamma_2'(r),\gamma_1'(r))\neq 0$

Considering the coefficients in the given problem:
I get the condition $-\gamma_2(r)'+\Phi(r)\gamma_1'(r)=0$

Now I am not really sure how to continue.
I could just guess and get for example
(*)

$\gamma_1(r)=r$

$\gamma_2(r)=r$

$\Phi(r)=1$

This would mean I would get
$u(r,r)=1$ for $r \in \mathbb{R}$ as boundary condition.
My question is, can I just choose the condition like I did in (*)? As far as I did understand the topic my answer should be correct, is it?